# apscheduler not working . Import Error: No module named Scheduler found

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am getting import error while I am trying to run my code. Scheduler module is not found. when I tried bypassing the error by using `backgroundScheduler()`, I found it doesn't support cron-like job scheduling i.e `add_cron_job`. Where am I going wrong ?

```py
import ConfigParser
import pymysql # Allows us to connect to a database and issue queries
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import threading, time
import json
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import os
import logging
import smtplib # Import smtplib for the actual sending function




logging.basicConfig()
config = None
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# init_config_parser
# Initialize a config parser based on filename
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
def init_config_parser():
    global config
    config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open('settings.cfg'))
    return config


# This is called when the runReportsScheduler.py file is first run.
# There is an infinite loop such that the script will never terminate.

# Every x number of seconds, the script reloads the latest
# notification schedules from the database. These notification schedules
# can be changed from the webapp in the configuration page.
# Then, it reschedules all of the email notifications accordingly.

# The scheduler calls the function email_send everytime it should be fired.


def email_send(emails):

    From = 'web@weber.com'
    To = emails

    message = """Please ignore this email.


    This is a test e-mail message.
   """
    try :
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtphost.qualcomm.com')
        smtpObj.sendmail(From, To.split(','), message) # the second parameter expects a    list for multiple contacts
        smtpObj.quit()
    except SMTPException:
        print "Error: unable to send email"

if __name__ == '__main__':

    init_config_parser()
    updateInterval = float(config.get("SCHEDULER",'updateInterval'))
    thisURL = str(config.get("SCHEDULER",'rootURL'))

    #refreshingFunction(50687,False)

    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        print "This is the #"+str(i)+" time I am looping, on a "+str(updateInterval)+"s interval"


        conn = pymysql.connect(host="10.52.244.877", user="wciadmin", passwd="admybutt", db="weekly_reports")
        cur = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM reminders_table ORDER BY id DESC")


        currentJobs = sched.get_jobs()
        row = cur.fetchone()
        while row is not None:
        # this is for each row in the DB
            thisQuery = row['id']


            # delete any current jobs with that query name
            for job in currentJobs:
                if int(job.name) == int(thisQuery):
                    sched.unschedule_job(job)

        thisRuntimes = row['runtimes'].split(";")
        if len(thisRuntimes) > 0 and row['runtimes'] != "":
            for thisSchedule in thisRuntimes:
                daysOfWeek = thisSchedule.split("-")[0]
                times = thisSchedule.split("-")[1].split(",")
                for time in times:
                hour = time.split(":")[0]
                if hour[0] == "0":
                    hour = hour[1]
                min = time.split(":")[1]

                sched.add_cron_job(email_send, day_of_week=daysOfWeek, hour=hour, minute=min, args=[row['emails']]) 
    row = cur.fetchone()


conn.close()

sleep(updateInterval) #in seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it. Scheduler() has been deprecated in apscheduler v3.0. I downloaded version 2.1.2 and it solved my problem. the link to v2.1.2 is below :

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/APScheduler/2.1.2#downloads

Comment: Not deprecated -- removed entirely.